# Flatten lists of lists that contain dictionaries into a single dict

Tags: python

I have many dictionaries as lists within a list, and I want to flatten the lists out so I get a single dictionary which contains the same keys and their values.

For example:

```
 final_results= [[{'lat': '29.97659',
   'lon': '-90.40897',
   'name': 'Hahnville',
   'admin1': 'Louisiana',
   'admin2': 'Saint Charles Parish',
   'cc': 'US'}],
 [{'lat': '29.97678',
   'lon': '-90.40877',
   'name': 'Hahnville',
   'admin1': 'Louisiana',
   'admin2': 'Saint Charles Parish',
   'cc': 'US'}],
 [{'lat': '29.95465',
   'lon': '-90.07507',
   'name': 'New Orleans',
   'admin1': 'Louisiana',
   'admin2': 'Orleans Parish',
   'cc': 'US'}]]


d = {}
for k in final_results[0][0].keys():
    d[k]=tuple(d[k] for d in final_results[0])
```

Only gives me values for a single one:

```
{'lat': ('29.97659',),
 'lon': ('-90.40897',),
 'name': ('Hahnville',),
 'admin1': ('Louisiana',),
 'admin2': ('Saint Charles Parish',),
 'cc': ('US',)}
```

Expected result:

```
{'lat': ('29.97659','29.97678','29.95465'),
 'lon': ('-90.40897','-90.40877','-90.40897'),
 'name': ('Hahnville','Hahnville','New Orleans'),
 'admin1': ('Louisiana','Louisiana','Louisiana'),
 'admin2': ('Saint Charles Parish','Saint Charles Parish','Orleans Parish'),
 'cc': ('US','US','US')}
```

Comment: Have a look at [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: `{g: [v[1] for v in i] for g, i in groupby(sorted(p for d, *_ in final_results for p in d.items()), itemgetter(0))}`. [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pprint

final_results = [[{'lat': '29.97659',
                   'lon': '-90.40897',
                   'name': 'Hahnville',
                   'admin1': 'Louisiana',
                   'admin2': 'Saint Charles Parish',
                   'cc': 'US'}],
                 [{'lat': '29.97678',
                   'lon': '-90.40877',
                   'name': 'Hahnville',
                   'admin1': 'Louisiana',
                   'admin2': 'Saint Charles Parish',
                   'cc': 'US'}],
                 [{'lat': '29.95465',
                   'lon': '-90.07507',
                   'name': 'New Orleans',
                   'admin1': 'Louisiana',
                   'admin2': 'Orleans Parish',
                   'cc': 'US'}]]

res = defaultdict(list)
for lst in final_results:
    for d in lst:
        for k, v in d.items():
            res[k].append(v)

pprint.pprint(res)
```

**Output**

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'admin1': ['Louisiana', 'Louisiana', 'Louisiana'],
             'admin2': ['Saint Charles Parish',
                        'Saint Charles Parish',
                        'Orleans Parish'],
             'cc': ['US', 'US', 'US'],
             'lat': ['29.97659', '29.97678', '29.95465'],
             'lon': ['-90.40897', '-90.40877', '-90.07507'],
             'name': ['Hahnville', 'Hahnville', 'New Orleans']})
```

Answer (score 1):

something like the below (using defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict
holder = defaultdict(list)

data = [[{'lat': '29.97659',
   'lon': '-90.40897',
   'name': 'Hahnville',
   'admin1': 'Louisiana',
   'admin2': 'Saint Charles Parish',
   'cc': 'US'}],
 [{'lat': '29.97678',
   'lon': '-90.40877',
   'name': 'Hahnville',
   'admin1': 'Louisiana',
   'admin2': 'Saint Charles Parish',
   'cc': 'US'}],
 [{'lat': '29.95465',
   'lon': '-90.07507',
   'name': 'New Orleans',
   'admin1': 'Louisiana',
   'admin2': 'Orleans Parish',
   'cc': 'US'}]]
for entry in data:
  for k,v in entry[0].items():
    holder[k].append(v)
print(holder)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'lat': ['29.97659', '29.97678', '29.95465'], 'lon': ['-90.40897', '-90.40877', '-90.07507'], 'name': ['Hahnville', 'Hahnville', 'New Orleans'], 'admin1': ['Louisiana', 'Louisiana', 'Louisiana'], 'admin2': ['Saint Charles Parish', 'Saint Charles Parish', 'Orleans Parish'], 'cc': ['US', 'US', 'US']})
```

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler than you expect..

```
results={}
for result in final_results:
    for key,val in result[0].items():
        if key not in results:results[key]=(val,)
        else:results[key]+=(val,)
print(results)
```

```
{
'lat': ('29.97659', '29.97678', '29.95465'),
 'lon': ('-90.40897', '-90.40877', '-90.07507'),
 'name': ('Hahnville', 'Hahnville', 'New Orleans'),
 'admin1': ('Louisiana', 'Louisiana', 'Louisiana'),
 'admin2': ('Saint Charles Parish', 'Saint Charles Parish', 'Orleans Parish'),
 'cc': ('US', 'US', 'US')
}
```